# PHP query not working to check database for username

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So I made a function that checks if the data that the user enters is already in my database of users. The function works in a testing environment (but runs on open of the page). For some reason it assigns the user input to the $username function regardless of the outcome of the query. I think I may have to AJAX it but I don't know how.

```
  <?php

  function checkIfEntered($data, $conn)
  {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE username= '" . $data . "'";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {

      /* determine number of rows result set */
      $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      /* close result set */
      mysqli_free_result($result);

    }

    if (($row_cnt) >= 1)
    {
      return TRUE;
    }

    if (($row_cnt) == 0)
    {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  // define variables and set to empty values
  $servername = "localhost"; $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "MyDatabase";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  $email = '';
  $emailErr = '';
  $usernameErr = '';
  $UserPasswordErr = '';
  $username = '';
  $UserPassword = '';
  $confirm = '';
  $confirmErr = '';
  function test_input($data) 
  {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
  }
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
     if (empty($_POST["username"])) 
     {
       $usernameErr = "username is required";
     } 
     else 
     {
      if (checkIfEntered($username, $conn))
     {
      $usernameErr = "There is already a user with the username: " . $username;
     }
     else
     {
       $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not even calling the "checkIfEntered" function. Instead, you are calling "isEnteredUsername" function, which I don't see it here. So the code is always going in else and assigning the POST value to $username.
I am not sure why you think AJAXing it will solve the problem, but you can use AJAX call on document ready or some event like this $.ajax({ ... }) as explained here.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: This was actually a mistake I made when transferring the code to stack overflow. in my main document I don't make this mistake. I just corrected it in the post, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

you are forgot return num of record this function "checkIfEntered"

```
<?php
function checkIfEntered($data, $conn)
{
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE username= '" . $data . "'";

  if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    /* close result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return  $row_cnt;
  }

  if (($row_cnt) >= 1)
  {
    return TRUE;
  }

  if (($row_cnt) == 0)
  {
    return FALSE;
  }
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
// define variables and set to empty values
$servername = "localhost"; $username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "MyDatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = '';
$emailErr = '';
$usernameErr = '';
$UserPasswordErr = '';
$username = '';
$UserPassword = '';
$confirm = '';
$confirmErr = '';
function test_input($data) 
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
  if (empty($_POST["username"])) 
  {
    $usernameErr = "username is required";
  } 
  else 
  {
    if (checkIfEntered(test_input($_POST["username"]), $conn))
    {
      $usernameErr = "There is already a user with the username: " . $username;
    }
    else
    {
      $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: This is not actually the problem. I believe that I have a timeout issue.

Comment: you add tine out for php :  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0=NOLIMIT

Comment: So the actaull error was that $username was not set when I used the function.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with this code is the function `checkIfEntered()` is coming up false because when you pass the  `$username`  parameter it has not been assigned. so it is coming up as false.

Code:

```
  if (checkIfEntered(test_input($_POST["username"]), $conn))
{
  $usernameErr = "There is already a user with the username: " . $username;
}
else
{
  $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
}
```

Correction

```
  $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);

  if (checkIfEntered(test_input($_POST["username"]), $conn))
{
  $usernameErr = "There is already a user with the username: " . $username;
  $username = '';
  //set username back to nothing to avoid more errors.
}
else
{
  $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
}
```